# How to avoid that a string splits on every whitespace in command line

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program in which the user can type in some informations about a customer and then open a MS Word model (*.dotx). After that he can directly archive it with another program. So I click on a button which I created for MS Word and then it should open the other program (the archive program) and pass the path to the *.dotx file to it. I got this code to pass the path and open the archive program:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "Word " + secondArgument;
p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
p.Start();
```

The string `secondArgument` ist the path to the file and `fileName` is the path to the exe file of the archive program.

To get the arguments in the archive program, I use this code in `Form_Load()`:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Then I use a MsgBox to look if it's correctly passed. But it isn't. The name of the .dotx file has whitespaces in it (e.g. "path\This is a test file.dotx"). So the output of `MessageBox.Show(args[0])` is "path\This". How can I avoid that it splits at every whitespace?

Suggestions appreciated :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to surround it with quotation marks:

```
 "This is a test file.dotx"
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx):

> Command line arguments are delimited by spaces. You can use double
>   quotation marks (") to include spaces within an argument.

Comment: My man! This is exactly what I need. Thank you. Nice to know that.